# Throws Fatal Python error using command 'python3' in cmd

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, pythonpath

Trying to use python3 on win10.

This is what I get when I try to use:

```
> python3 myscript.py

Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
        raise CodecRegistryError,\
                                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Current thread 0x00001e44 (most recent call first):
```

Possible problem, that I have 2.7 on my system as well. 
Using commands `py` and `python` works. They run the python 2.7 scripts without problem.

I have added my folders to PYTHONPATH.

[image]

Does somebody know the answer?

Comment: Can you also add the code from myscript.py?

Comment: Running a python virtual environment will save you from this headache in the future. Look under the packages for virtualenv and you will see how nice that is.

Comment: The syntax has changed in python 3. Intead of, say, `raise ValueError, 'oops'`, you need `raise ValueError('oops')`, See https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changes-to-exceptions

Comment: @PeterSteele I don't see how virtualenv helps with syntax changes between python 2 and 3.

Comment: Notice that since you didn't provide a running example, we have to guess at what is on the next line after `raise CodecRegistryError,\`. I reproduced this problem with a one line example: `raise ValueError, 'oops'`. Boiling problems down to the minimum really helps!

Comment: @tdelaney yeah except for the fact that he is trying to run a python 3 script and his system is choosing python 2 instead. That is the first problem that needs to be solved, not what the traceback is throwing atm, hence his clarification on adding stuff to the PythonPath

Comment: Don't add those folders to PYTHONPATH! When you run either `python` or `python3`, python figures out the right paths to its own internal folders. You have a problem with windows when you double-click a .py file because you can only have one association. But when you run python directly, you shouldn't need a PYTHONPATH unless you have external non-installed modules you want to run.

Comment: @PeterSteele - he is explicitly running python3. Now, either that's a python 2 program or because he unwisely mixed python 2 and 3 in his PYTHONPATH. virtualenv is great when you need multiple environments, but not needed when you have 1 python 2 and 1 python 3 installed.

Comment: @tdelaney im going to say its because he mixed the PythonPath. While yes you dont need to have virtualenv for python 2 and python 3 since its two very different installs, it does make things a bit easier to work with and separate them down the road. Thats the biggest reason I mentioned it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141675/discussion-between-peter-steele-and-tdelaney).

Comment: @tdelaney Then which version should I add to PATH? Which folders hould I delete from PYTONPATH? I'm a little confused.

Comment: As was stated already, absolutely *none* of those folders ever belongs in `PYTHONPATH`. You can add the installation and Scripts directories to `PATH`, as it seems you've copied, linked, or renamed 3.x python.exe as "python3.exe". But generally you'll be better off using virtual environments when developing for multiple platforms. If you have scripts that need a particular version, ensure that .py[w] files are associated with the py[w].exe launcher and use shebangs to run the right version.

Comment: @MattSom, I've added suggestions to my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you mixed python 2 and 3 environments in your PYTHONPATH. You told python 3 that its perfectly fine to find and import modules from the python 2 distribution. And That will end in tears.

Python already knows about its standard installation directories when you run it. That covers the stdlib and any modules you explicitly install (e.g, via pip). PYTHONPATH is only needed for stuff you didn't install but just copied somewhere.

PYTHONPATH is not (usually) useful for either the `scripts` directory or python.exe itself. scripts and the .exe need to be found by the operating system, not python, so need to be on the PATH.

Window managers can add a complication by associating a file extension with a program to run that extension. So, in Windows, you have to choose whether python 2 or 3 scripts are runnable by clicking the desktop. Python installers try to be clever by creating wrappers that know which python to call.

After installing on windows, you likely want to add the scripts and .exe directories to your path. You can do that for both python 2 and 3... with a little problem. If you have like-named scripts in python 2 and 3, the first one in the path wins.

I think you can remove PYTHONPATH completely and make sure these are in PATH. My windows python install is a bit different than yours, so I couldn't test to make sure.

```
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\Scripts
C:\Python36
C:\Python36\Scripts
```

Comment: If Python 3 is installed you should have the py[w].exe launcher associated with .py[w] files and use [virtual] shebangs -- which is all explained quite verbosely and carefully in the docs, so I don't know why we have to rehash it here, but it seems we're cursed to repeat ourselves millions of times for people who refuse to read.

Comment: @eryksun yeah, i've seen several installers do different things but don't use windows enough to keep up with it. I was hoping to be vague on that point.

Comment: I've done as you told, and also renamed python3.exe back to python.exe. Now I don't even have to use `python3` as a command, `python` runs 2.7 and 3.6 scripts as well as it seems. Thank you, kind sir!

Comment: Try to avoid leaping to conclusions without research and careful experiment. `python.exe` from a particular version does not run 2.7 and 3.6 scripts, which is something you could easily confirm with simple tests. py.exe, on the other hand, is a launcher that will run the version of python.exe that's specified on the shebang line of a script. .py files should be associated with `Python.File`, which should have an `open` command that executes a script using py.exe.

Comment: The OP renamed python3.exe *back* to python.exe. In that context saying "`python` runs 2.7 and 3.6 scripts as well" implies a single `python.exe` executable is able to run both 2.7 and 3.6 scripts. The obvious reading of a statement like that is that the OP is running `python "path\to\script.py"`. Unless a distro has created its own custom multi-Python launcher named `python.exe`, then that's not possible. Given what I know about the OP's approach to things -- rushing in without research and reading only to make an unholy mess -- I felt justified in strongly suggesting a different approach.

Comment: tdelaney, sorry, my comment was in response to the OP, and I forgot to include @MattSom. (BTW, I did not downvote your answer; I'm one of the upvotes.)

Comment: @eryksun - sorry about being grumpy... !

Answer (score 1):

Add python to the main PATH variable.

```
C:\Python35;C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python35\Scripts\
```

replace the version # with whatever you are using. Also please look into virtualenv for python as well. Its under the libs and can be installed via PIP.

It will save you so much time and headache when running multiple versions on one computer and is super easy to use!